# Save Tkinter "root" image

Tags: python, tkinter, save

I'm doing a research project where I need to generate some images to use in an experiment. However, I can't seem to save the images that I created in Tkinter with python. I'm generating some images in different patterns, but I can't find any solution on how I could save it.

Would be awesome if someone knew how I could proceed, and hope you have a nice day! :)

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter, Tkconstants, tkFileDialog
import random

root = Tk()

root.configure(background='white')

green = PhotoImage(file="C:\Users\oscar\Desktop\Patterns\green.pbm")
red = PhotoImage(file="C:\Users\oscar\Desktop\Patterns\\red.pbm")

r = 0
c = 0

while r <= 16:
    for c in range(17):
        label = Label(root, image=random.choice([green, red]))
        label.grid(row=r, column=c)
        label.bd = 0
        label.configure(border=0)
    r += 1


root.mainloop()

# Here is the closest solution I have for saving, but it doesn't work
root.filename = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("jpeg files","*.jpg"),("all files","*.*")))
```

Comment: What does "can't seem to save" mean? Why can't you save them? Your code doesn't show you even trying to save them. Are you simply asking _how_ to save an image?

Comment: I think you'd be better off creating the image in [Pillow](https://python-pillow.org/) rather than compositing labels together and trying to screenshot them in Tkinter. Doing image manipulation with a library not specifically designed for image manipulation is a recipe for a painful experience.

Comment: Thank you Bryan and Kevin! :) Yes, I basically want to save it Bryan, and I'll do it in Pillow as you suggested Kevin ;) Have a nice day!